# Accuracy of nanosecond component in Ruby Time

Tags: ruby

I have a duration in seconds with millisecond precision, 420.854 (420 seconds and 854 milliseconds).

I want to format it like (Minutes):(Seconds).(Milliseconds) so I tried this:

```
Time.at(421.854).utc.strftime('%M:%S.%L')
```

The result: `"07:01.853"` As you can see it's off by one millisecond.

So I dug into it further:

```
Time.at(421.854).nsec # Output: 853999999 (expected 854000000)
```

I believe the unexpected output of the above is the cause of the problem. Some numbers work as expected though for example:

```
Time.at(421.855).nsec # Output 855000000 as expected
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on solving this, the best I can come up with is to "fix" the nanosecond component afterwards with `(nanoseconds.to_f / 1000000).round * 1000000` but I feel like there might be a better approach. Really appreciate any thoughts on the subject.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect this is due to `Time.at` taking a binary floating point number - that it has nothing to do with time at all.

I'm not a Ruby dev, but in IEEE-754 64-bit floating point types, the closest value to 421.854 is exactly

```
421.85399999999998499333742074668407440185546875
```

... so my guess is that that exact value is being truncated, effectively.

(The nearest 32-bit floating point value is 421.85400390625.)

If you use a [`Rational`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Rational.html) instead to specify it as effectively an integer number of milliseconds (`Rational(421854, 1000)`), you may well find that works. Alternatively, use `at(seconds, microseconds_with_frac)`:

```
Time.at(421, 854000).utc.strftime('%M:%S.%L')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon Skeet. Both your suggestions work. For the record:
`Time.at(421.854).nsec # Outputs 853999999`, 

`Time.at(Rational(421.854 * 1000, 1000)).nsec # Outputs 854000000`, 

`Time.at(Rational(421854, 1000)).nsec # Outputs 854000000`, 

`Time.at(421, 854000).nsec # Outputs 854000000`

Thanks again

Comment: @Bruce: Excellent - glad to hear it!

Comment: And simplest solution of all: Time.at(421.854.rationalize).nsec